# Can't import JGit into gradle build script

Tags: android, gradle, jgit

I would like to use `JGit` in my `app/gradle.build` script to be able to get the current tag to create the version name for my android project.

I have declared the dependency in my root `build.gradle` below

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.5.0.201909110433-r'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

but after I sync, I still don't have JGit available in my `app/build.gradle`

```
def versionNameFromTag() {
   Git git = new Git(repository) // <- Unresolved Reference: Git
}
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to get JGit into my root `/build.gradle` file with the following dependency declaration fixes

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.5.+"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

// Now Compiles with JGit dependencies
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git
import org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.*
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.*
```

But my `app/build.gradle` still can't import JGit

```
// Still doesn't compile
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git // <- Unresolved Reference: Git

def versionNameFromTag() {
   Git git = new Git(repository) // <- Unresolved Reference: Git
}
```

Comment: JGit is released to maven central (https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit-parent/5.5.1.201910021850-r/pom) why do you reference the eclipse.org repository? Also, there are two `repositories` directives with different settings. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I'm not familiar with script-level dependencies or maven. I was following the jgit cookbook repository [here](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/build.gradle).

Comment: Your build.gradle file looks quite different from what you linked to. Maybe there lies the problem.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Please see updates. I was in declaring the dependency incorrectly, as you suggested. However, I still can't get `JGit` into my `app/build.gradle`

Comment: I don't know what `buildscript` does. My Gradle build files use `dependencies` unnested.

Answer (score 1):

Each Gradle script is independent and when you add dependencies using the `buildscript` block, these are local to the script in which they are declared. There is no propagation of these dependencies to included projects.

You have a couple options, in order of preference:

- Add this dependency through the [included build in `buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources), which will then make it available to all your projects.
- Duplicate the declaration in all scripts that will require `jgit`